# Can I mix three 18650s with different brands?

Tags: batteries, lithium, bms, 18650

I have three 18650 batteries with different brands, but the same voltage and capacity. Can I mix them using a 3s BMS with balancer without a risk?

Comment: I wouldn't. In theory it should be OK but the cells may age differently.

Comment: You should include a picture of your balancer, as well as the cells, just so that we can be sure you got what you think you got.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN mix them if they're the same voltage and capacity, but not without a risk. Even those of the same brand and model will have slight discrepancies among them, and even more so if they're of a different brand or model.
Since you have a balancer, that would help greatly, though most simple, cheap balancers only balances during charging.

**FIRST**, you have to make sure that the cells are ACTUALLY of the indicated capacity, and not the cheap Chinese junk with the marked capacity being as much as 90% off.

**SECOND**, you have to be **100% SURE** that you actually have a **BALANCER**, and not just a voltage monitor which does no balancing but only keeps any single cell from going too high or too low.
If your balancer has 3 large(r) resistors (that is, one for each cell), then it should have the ability to balance. Those resistors serve to take away a portion of the charging current for the cell which has reached full charge voltage.
I still wouldn't rely too much on those cheap balancers, as they do no balancing during discharge, and only start balancing at the end of charge.
You have to check cell voltages periodically, to make sure they didn't go out of balance, as they may age differently, or it may be for whatever reason.

You should include a picture of your balancer, as well as of the cells, just so that we can be sure that what you have is an actual balancer and not just a cell voltage monitor and charge and load disconnector, and that your cells are not the false-capacity-marked ones (if you didn't buy a brand name through an authorized or reliable distributor).